# Content Version Issue in Community

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, customer-community

I have created a autocomplete functionality for contacts. once I selected contact I am redirecting page with the help of contact ID I am fetching the contact and  Content Version details. it's work fine in System admin. but when I log in with community user doesn't work.

Is there any additional access we need to give for Content version.

Please help me out.

Apex Code----

```
//-- default initialization method
    public void init(){
        String peopleId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pid');
        if(peopleId!=null){
            System.debug('People Contact Search ');
            objContact = [SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName, Name, MobilePhone, Email, Birthdate, Gender__c,Designation_Name__c, Department__c, Faculty__c, Office_Building__r.Name, Office_Room__c,CVUE_Student_Number__c,DOB__c FROM Contact WHERE Id =: peopleId];                        
            findProfileImage(peopleId);
        }else{
            System.debug('User Contact Search');
            objContact = [SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName, Name, MobilePhone, Email, Birthdate, Gender__c, Designation_Name__c, Department__c, Faculty__c, Office_Building__r.Name, Office_Room__c,CVUE_Student_Number__c,DOB__c,Contact_Address_Line_1__c,Contact_Address_Line_2__c,Contact_City__c,Contact_State__c,Contact_Country__c ,Contact_Zip_Code__c FROM Contact WHERE Id =: contactId]; 
            findProfileImage(contactId);
        }
        System.debug('Contact Details : '+objContact);

        //-- get base URL for user photograph       
        if(contentVersionList.size()>0){
            String baseURL = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();                                
            publicURL = baseURL.replace('visual','content');
            publicURL+='/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'+contentVersionList[0].id;          
        }else{
            publicURL='';
        }
        System.debug('publicURL:'+publicURL);               
    }

    //-- get profile image url  
    public void findProfileImage(String conId){
        System.debug('Profile method start : '+conId);
        Set<String> cdIDSet = new Set<String>();
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdl : [SELECT ContentDocumentId,Id,LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: conId]){
            cdIDSet.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId);
            System.debug('ContentDocumentLink : '+cdl);
        }
        System.debug('cdIDSet : '+cdIDSet);
        contentVersionList = [SELECT id, Title ,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: cdIDSet AND Title ='Profie Image'];
        System.debug('contentVersionList : '+contentVersionList);
        if(contentVersionList.size()>0){
            contentDocumentList = [SELECT id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id =: contentVersionList[0].ContentDocumentId];
        }
        if(contentVersionList.size()>0){
            String baseURL = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();                                
            publicURL = baseURL.replace('visual','content');
            publicURL+='/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'+contentVersionList[0].id;          
        }else{
            publicURL='';
        }
        System.debug('publicURL:'+publicURL);
    }
```